# Host 'PC-NAME' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, xampp, visual-studio-2019

[image]

That's the error I get. I'm using VS2019 and XAMPP.
I've tried different ways but it don't work.

Any suggestions pls?

I already tried different ways like inserting --skip-grant-tables in my.ini, editing config.inc.php, configuring privileges.

Comment: How was the user that is used in creating the database connection created? `show create user USERNAME`? Where is the connection code? Edit question with these detail as text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)